# Rooted Nexus One doesn't show up in Banshee

Tags: 11.04, banshee, android

I have follow the instructions found here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=624240

But my nexus one doesn't show up in Banshee (the mass storage plugin is enabled). Has anyone had any luck getting this working?

This is with Banshee 1.9.5.

Comment: Which version(s) of Banshee have you tried this with?  There was a packaging issue with Banshee 1.9.5 that was causing problems with Banshee's hardware detection, so if you're using that version, that might be the cause.

Comment: yeah, it's 1.9.5 in Natty. Do you know if there is a bug for this already?

Comment: There's a bug report, and actually the issue has already been fixed in the latest Banshee packages for Ubuntu. :)  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions you followed should no longer be necessary for getting Banshee to recognize your Nexus One.  Support for the Nexus One was added [in the Banshee 1.6 stable release](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/1-6-0/).  However, there was a [recent bug in the Ubuntu packages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/736631) for Banshee 1.9.5 that caused Banshee to build without a hardware manager.

The good news is, this has been fixed in the 1.9.6 release, which is available in the [Banshee Unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/banshee-unstable).  I'm not sure if the release has been pushed out in the Natty updates yet, but if it hasn't, it should be soon.  (If updating to Banshee 1.9.6 doesn't fix the problem, be sure to report back here, and we'll see if we can figure out what's going on.)

Comment: I'll update you when 1.9.6 shows up in the natty repo

Comment: That's all the issue was. As soon as Ubuntu updated Banshee to 1.9.6 the problem completely went away.

Comment: Glad to hear it!